# show a set is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $I$ be an open interval in $\Bbb R$ and let $f: I\to\Bbb R$ be a differentiable function.

1. Prove that the set $T=\{(x,y)\in I\times I : x<y\}$ is a connected subset of $\Bbb R^2$ with the standard topology.
2. Let $g:T \to\Bbb R$ be the function defined by $$ g(x,y) =\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$$
   Prove that $g(T) \subseteq f\,'(I) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}g(T)$

For (1) I think that it will be easier to show the set is path connected and thus connected. Should I be looking for the explicit path that will demonstrate this?

Comment: Stretches of mathematics should all be within the same MathJax code; don't enter and leave MathJax for every symbol. You can get braces in MathJax with `\{` and `\}`. You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Note that (2) yields a nice proof that the derivative of a function has the Intermediate Value Property. :)

Comment: An explicit path for 1 will do just fine.  If you visualize $T$ as a triangle the choice of path should be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It suffices to show that $ T $ is path-connected, as path-connectedness implies connectedness. The path-connectedness of $ T $ is easily visualized by producing a sketch of $ T $.
2. Let $ (x,y) \in T $. By the Mean-Value Theorem, there exists a $ c \in (x,y) \subseteq I $ such that
   $$
   g(x,y) = \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} = f'(c) \in f'[I].
   $$
   As $ (x,y) \in T $ is arbitrary, it follows that $ g[T] \subseteq f'[I] $.

   Next, for each $ x \in I $, we can find a sequence $ (y_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ in $ I $ such that $ x < y_{n} $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ and $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} y_{n} = x $. We clearly have
   $$
   f'(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x) - f(y_{n})}{x - y_{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} g(x,y_{n}),
   $$
   so $ (g(x,y_{n}))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is a sequence in $ g[T] $ that converges to $ f'(x) $. Hence, $ f'(x) \in \text{cl}(g[T]) $, and as $ x \in I $ is arbitrary, it follows that $ f'[I] \subseteq \text{cl}(g[T]) $.

---

**Conclusion:** $ g[T] \subseteq f'[I] \subseteq \text{cl}(g[T]) $.